# How can a user have user role privileges that the user has in the sub-site, in which the user is member of?

Tags: wordpress, multisite, user-management, wordpress-roles

e.g. a User **John** is registered from and is a member of **"SITE A"** in a multisite network, where his assigned role is **"Charter Member"**. So, what I want is that when JOHN visits **"SITE B"** he has the privileges (i.e. I can get his role) as he has in **"SITE A"**. But also I don't want to make JOHN member of **"SITE B"**

By default WordPress stores user capabilities/role in **user_meta** table but with site prefix like wp_3. Meaning that user role is **site-specific**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the plugin "WP Multisite User Sync" in wordpress codex

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Yes, I have checked it but this plugin and all plugins like this make a user member of all subsites to synchronize roles network-wide. which I don't want because I want is to keep the members list separate subsite wise but want their assigned role to be accessible network-wide.

Comment: without adding member in the site, you cannot give access permission to user for another site